# plotting the clustered data point based on Euclidean Distance Matrices

Tags: clustering, multidimensional-scaling

suppose I have two clusters, each of them have 5 points.

I know the Euclidean Distance Matrix [ 10 x 10].

Is it possible to draw the points in a N-D space? how to do so?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=mds.

Comment: thx for answer, is that any simple way to solve this problem, let say, i only got 10 points, and I would like to draw it on 2D plane. thx